# Ternary condition on onclick event with MUI material in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a event-calendar application in React. Code I have so far adds date items to the calendar list. When I click on the add date, if there is already a date added, I would like to have the possibility to "add more dates" in the locize key. PS: "t" is a locize key from https://locize.com/ for translation purpose.

```
/* Calculate dates to add before submitting.*/
    const handleAddDates = () => {
        const cursor = new Date(startDate);
        endDate.setHours(23, 59, 0, 0);

        const dates: EventDate[] = [];

        while (cursor <= endDate) {
            const dayOfTheWeek = weekdays[dayOfTheWeekToWeekdayKey[cursor.getDay()]];
            if (dayOfTheWeek.enabled) {
                const newStartDate = new Date(cursor);
                newStartDate.setHours(dayOfTheWeek.startTime.getHours());
                newStartDate.setMinutes(dayOfTheWeek.startTime.getMinutes());

                const newEndDate = new Date(cursor);
                newEndDate.setHours(dayOfTheWeek.endTime.getHours());
                newEndDate.setMinutes(dayOfTheWeek.endTime.getMinutes());

                dates.push({ startDate: newStartDate, endDate: newEndDate });
            }

            cursor.setDate(cursor.getDate() + 1);
        }

        onAddDates(dates);
    };
```

```
            <Button
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => handleAddDates()}
                disabled={Object.values(weekdays).some(
                    ({ startTime, endTime }) => !isValid(startTime) || !isValid(endTime),
                )}
            >
                {[t("CE Add date", "Add date")]}
            </Button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem? where is the error?

Comment: I cannot find the way to add the ternary condition to have singular "date" when just onClick has been hit once and "dates" when onClick has been hit more than once. Let me know if this isn't clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was the solution:

```js
import { useField } from "formik";

 // ... (rest of my code)

const DailyOrWeeklyDatesPicker = ({
 // ... (rest of my code)
    const [fieldDates, ,] = useField<EventDate[]>("eventDates");
  
   // ... (rest of my code)
   
    <Box>
            <Button
                <Button
                fullWidth
                    fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                    variant="contained"
                onClick={() => handleAddDates()}
                    onClick={() => handleAddDates()}
                disabled={Object.values(weekdays).some(
                    disabled={Object.values(weekdays).some(
                    ({ startTime, endTime }) => !isValid(startTime) || !isValid(endTime),
                        ({ startTime, endTime }) => !isValid(startTime) || !isValid(endTime),
                )}
                    )}
            >
                >
                {[t("CE Add date", "Add date")]}
                    {fieldDates.value.length > 0 ? (
            </Button>
                        <span>{[t("CE Add more dates", "Add more dates")]}</span>
                    ) : (
                        <span>{[t("CE Add date", "Add date")]}</span>
                    )}
                </Button>
            </Box>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).